# Ngx-charts not drawn after switching tabs with MatTabsModule

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material, ngx-charts

I created a graph using ngx-charts(https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/line-area-charts/line-chart) and want to display a different graph using Material Tabs (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api). When I switch between the Tabs the Graph is not drawn until I reload the whole page. Thats the code.

```
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab label="First"> <ngx-charts-line-chart
[view]="view"
[scheme]="colorScheme"
[legend]="legend"
[showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
[showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
[xAxis]="xAxis"
[yAxis]="yAxis"
[xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
[yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
[timeline]="timeline"
[results]="multi"
(select)="onSelect($event)"
(activate)="onActivate($event)"
(deactivate)="onDeactivate($event)"


  >
  </ngx-charts-line-chart> </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOXih.png) how it looks when I start it and [thats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWQFF.png) how it looks after I switched tabs.

Comment: create stackblitz example please

Answer (score 1):

It can be done this way

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="First" *ngIf="data.length">
            <ng-template matTabContent>
                <ngx-charts-line-chart [view]="[700, 400]" [scheme]="colorScheme" [legend]="legend"
                    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxis]="xAxis" [yAxis]="yAxis"
                    [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [timeline]="timeline" [results]="data">
                </ngx-charts-line-chart>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Second" *ngIf="data2.length">
            <ng-template matTabContent>
                <ngx-charts-line-chart [view]="[700, 400]" [scheme]="colorScheme" [legend]="legend"
                    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxis]="xAxis" [yAxis]="yAxis"
                    [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [timeline]="timeline" [results]="data2">
                </ngx-charts-line-chart>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

The complete code example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-khcctz?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I fall into the very same issue. I was able to find this: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/560. It is the same issue you are describing.

Using the layout from the example helped me. I.e. I wrapped my chart with the

```
      <div style="display: flex">
        <div style="flex: 1 1 50%; max-width: 50%; background-color: #efefef;">
          <div style="min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px">
            <ngx-charts-line-chart>
               ...
            </ngx-charts-line-chart>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and all became to work.